# For detached garage: buried cable or overhang?

Tags: garage, subpanel, 240v, detached-structure

I am a DIY guy, looking into bringing 240v into my detached garage. Will be running air compressor, welder. Will install a 100amp Subpanel.

Should the cable coming from the house (main panel) to the garage be buried or can it be overhanging? Distance from house to garage is 10 feet. I am trying to avoid digging a trench.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it should be overhead because that's _your_ preference. My preference is to bury it for the reasons noted in Milwrdfan's answer. When done in accordance to code, either is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: It depends on the ground and the buildings.  If the buildings are low and you have to put up poles that's a mark against overhead.  If the ground is rocky or there is a paved driveway between the buildings that's a mark against burial.   If you or someone else [really hates](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0551427/) seeing wires, that's a reason to bury them.   The answer is in the details.  If you dig a trench you can put a couple of empty conduits in it for internet, gas, water, whatever future use you might have.

Comment: How high are the walls of each building,  where the buildings are 10 feet apart?

Comment: House is about 17 feet, garage about 12, above ground. There is a wooden fence between the house (left) and the garage (right). Behind the fence is the backyard, dirt and grass. In front of the fence is pavement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what else is between the house and garage.  If there's ever a chance of bringing a tall ladder, vehicles, or other need for access, burying is the way to go to not have any overhead obstructions.  Putting the feed underground (in conduit for easier replacement in the future), will be more effort now, but a lot less safety concerns and better wire protection in the future.

Comment: I see. Yeah, the possibility of bringing a vehicle is there. Iguess I should gi with burried. Any suggestions as to the cable size? Thinking 2 inch conduit - 2awg alum. wire. I appreciate all suggestions.

Comment: @DavidE Unless it's a long run inside the buildings, 10 feet between buildings suggests that you could easily go to 1AWG Aluminum for very little more money for a full 100A feed, rather than be limited to 90A by using 2AWG. But 90 may well be perfectly adequate, too.

Comment: Well, it's 10 feet wall to wall. But after entering the house, cable has to go another 40 feet to the electrical panel. We'll see what the difference is in pricing, and go from there.

Comment: It also is necessary to do a load calculation to make sure the main panel can support the feed you're wanting to run to your garage.  You could certainly use larger conductors for easier future upgrades, but the load calculation will dictate how large of a breaker you could actually run.

Comment: Perfect job for RMC Rigid Metal Conduit for the underground bit.  If vehicles drive over it, burial is 12" cover.  If they don't, 6” cover.  It's costly but you're going 12 feet.